# How can I replace given values in an array with different values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, gsub

I have an array with some values that are nil. I want to replace those nils with "0"s.

So if my array is `@array = [nil, "2", nil, nil, "f"]`, I want this to happen:

```
 > @array.method
=> ["0", "2", "0", "0", "f"]
```

I tried using `gsub`, but I get an "undefined method 'gsub' for Array" error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `map` over your array and to check if the element is `nil`, if it's so then replace with `"0"`, if not then leave the value:

```
array = [nil, "2", nil, nil, "f"]
p array.map{|e| e.nil? ? '0' : e}
# => ["0", "2", "0", "0", "f"]
```

Another way is to use the Rails [`Object#presence`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence) method:

```
[nil, "2", nil, nil, "f"].map{|e| e.presence || '0'}
# => ["0", "2", "0", "0", "f"]
```

Comment: This also coverts `false` objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
@array = [nil, "2", nil, nil, "f"]
 => [nil, "2", nil, nil, "f"] 

@array.map {|x| x ? x : "0"}
=> ["0", "2", "0", "0", "f"]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function to replace nil in an array, so yes, map is the way to go. If a shorter version would make you happier, you could do:

```
array.map {|e| e ? e : "0"}
```